# No LSE connection to STM32. Is it OK?

Tags: oscillator, cortex-m3

I'm developing board which have STM32F103VET6. I don't need RTC so is it OK to not connect the OSE32_* pins to external oscillator? Will there be any side-effects? All the reference design I found all have a 32.768KHz oscillator connected to them. So I'm afraid losing other functions besides RTC.

The datasheet is [here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00191185.pdf).

Comment: Datasheet.....?

Comment: @Grissiom - We generally require that users link in the datasheet when it will be required to answer a question.  Please edit the part number to link to the datasheet.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not cause any problems leaving it out. Sometimes a low frequency secondary oscillator like this might be used for more than one peripheral (e.g. alt clock for timer) but in this case I think it is only used for the RTC.
Also, in this case it looks like even if you leave it out you can still clock the RTC from one of the other oscillators (HSE OSC or LSI RC)

The clock tree diagram in the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00191185.pdf) seems to confirm this, note the LSE OSC only goes to the RTCCLK mux (with another 2 options noted above for the RTC clock) and nowhere else:

[image: OSC32 Clock Inputs]